# how to check current & upgrade to firestore version that supports != operator in .where clause

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As per firestore release documentation,

Version 7.21.0 - September 17, 2020
Cloud Firestore
Added not-in and != query operators for use with .where().

However, I am still getting "Argument of type '"!="' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFilterOp'.ts"

How do I check my current cloud firestore version and upgrade to be able to use the != operator

Comment: How do you declare Firebase and Firestore in your app?

Comment: firebase functions

Comment: Can you clarify the question by adding a tag for what your coding platform is, and also include the code that's generating the error? The use of`WhereFilterOp` may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your coding language was not included in the question tags but for clarity here's a bit more info.

That's the literal explanation of the feature that was added in the documentation for [Query Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) Read a bit further to see how the implementation is used.

`!=` means not equal to, but the implementation is different for each language.

For example, in Swift it's it's the actual text `isNotEqualTo` used like this

```
let notEqualQuery = citiesRef.whereField("capital", isNotEqualTo: false)
```

in Java it's the text `whereNotEqualTo`

```
citiesRef.whereNotEqualTo("capital", false);
```

Web is in fact the string "!=". Note we're using `.where`, not WhereFilterOp

```
citiesRef.where("capital", "!=", false);
```